# Parse JSON in TypeScript - add 'data' tag

Tags: json, angular, typescript, parsing, treetable

Having a **JSON** that looks like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "position":3,
      "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "position":2,
      "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
   }
]
```

Is it possible by **any** means to make it like:

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "data":{  
            "id":1,
            "position":3,
            "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
         }
      },
      {  
         "data":{  
            "id":2,
            "position":2,
            "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I need that **data** tag to identify objects for a [TreeTable](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/treetable) implementation for which my given JSON is not conformed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `map` function to change item's shape.

For first level we create a new object `{ data: }` and then assign to `data` property the result of `array.map`.

```js
const array = [  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "position":3,
      "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "position":2,
      "articleNumber":"ServiceElement"
   }
];

const mapped = { data: array.map(item => ({ data: item }))};
console.log(mapped);
```

Comment: Straight forward solution. Might be nice to add some explanation aswell.

Comment: It works almost perfect. The problem is that this is generating an array of 'data' objects: [  
   {  
      "data":[ ...    and not an object 'data' containing array of data objects, like in my example